# Is it possible to do a full width dialog but with margin at top and vertical scroll in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, android-jetpack-compose, customdialog

I need to make a dialog like the one you can see in the image below, but I didn't find any information that would help me to do it. It should appear with down to top animations and when dragging down, the dialog disappears with the top to down animation. Is there any way to do this? Should it be a Dialog or does it have to be another type of object?

I really have no idea how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: This is a BottomSheet as far as I can see, not a dialog. Have a look, it's easy to implement.

Comment: @CodePoet BottomSheetDialogFragment, is that what you mean? Does this allow you to make a layout like the one I showed above and place the animations I want?

Comment: Look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#ModalBottomSheetLayout(kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material.ModalBottomSheetState,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function0)) for ModalBottomSheetLayout. And you can use ModalBottomSheetState for animations.

Comment: @CodePoet Just one more question: Does it make sense to have a ViewModel for this type of layout? I need to fetch data from the API.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense.